# How can I add button click for call a method if I click icon next month in the datepicker on vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vue-component, vuetify.js

I want to ask. How can I add button click for call a method if I click icon next month in the datepicker?

Look at this : [image]

How can I do it?

Update :

I using vuetify : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers#date-pickers-allowed-dates

Comment: If you don't have access to the button's code then add the click handler to the parent that you have access to. Your listener will be invoked when button is clicked, because of event bubbling. Just make sure to add the check in your listener to see what has been clicked.

Comment: From what i can gather so far from it's documentation is that it'll emit `input` event. That event is emitted for all clicks so you'll need to add the check that i mentioned before.

Comment: @a1626 I try `<v-date-picker @input="test">`, but it does not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're looking for something like this:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers#date-pickers-react-to-displayed-month-year-change

Basically you should use the `picker-date.sync` prop and watch for its changes using a watcher.

```html
<v-date-picker v-model="date" :picker-date.sync="pickerDate"/>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      pickerDate: null,
    }
  ),
  watch: {
    pickerDate (newval,oldval) {
      // here you can check if month changed using newval and oldval
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Hi. I want to ask again. can i display all dates this month? for example when the datepicker show, it will console.log () from October 14 to October 31. when I select November, it will console.log () from November 1 to November 30. How can i do it?

Comment: @SuccessMan this is something you have to do manually. Once you got the current month you should create an array from the first day (or from today) to the last day of the month. You could use momentjs (or vue-moment, specifically for vue) which is a library with a lot of helpful functions for dates

Comment: Ok, thank you. previously I thought it could be done automatically on vuetify

Comment: @SuccessMan Unfortunately not. If you will use momentjs this is a function which could help you: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/days-in-month/

Comment: okay thanks. but how can  i install moment js in the vuetify?

Comment: @SuccessMan use vue-moment as a plugin for Vue, it's the same. Here you have the guide: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58387320/is-alloweddate-not-usable-for-async-or-ajax-on-the-vuetify

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
   $(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-next', function () {
     console.log('next');  
    })

    $(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-prev', function () {
      console.log('prev');  
    })
```

Comment: I use vuetify https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers#date-pickers-allowed-dates

Answer (score 0):

I got these events on Vuetify's v-date-picker

in template:

```
  <v-date-picker
      ref="cal"
      ...
   >
```

in script:

```
mounted() {
  var vm = this;
  document.querySelector("[aria-label='Next month']").addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('next');
    var yyyy_mm = vm.$refs.cal.$data.tableDate;
    console.log(yyyy_mm);
  })
  document.querySelector("[aria-label='Previous month']").addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('previous');
    var yyyy_mm = vm.$refs.cal.$data.tableDate;
    console.log(yyyy_mm);
  })
}
```

and you can override aria-label

```
next-month-aria-label="NextMonth"
prev-month-aria-label="PreviousMonth"
```

Answer (score 0):

DatePickerTemplate

```
<v-date-picker @update:picker-date="updatePickedMonth"></v-date-picker>
```

//Js function:

```
updatePickedMonth(value){
 console.log(value) // will return ex: 2021-09
}
```