# Is allowedDate not usable for async or ajax on the vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I want to ask

```
methods: {
    allowedDates(date) {
        console.log(date) 
    }
},
```

it will console.log all date on every month selected

But if I add script ajax/async like this :

```
methods: {
    allowedDates(date) {
        console.log(date)
        this.getData({appDate: date}); // this is async/call ajax on the vuex store
    }
},
```

it's async without stopping

is allowedDate not usable for async or ajax?

docs : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers#date-pickers-allowed-dates

**Update**

I try to testing for make sure like this

If my code like this :

```
methods: {
    allowedDates(date) {
        if(date=='2019-10-17')
            return true
    }
},
```

It works. It just enable date = 2019-10-17. besides that date, disabled

But if my code like this :

```
methods: {
    allowedDates(date) {
        axios.get('https://myapi.com/api/schedules')
        .then(response => {
            if(date=='2019-10-17')
                return true
        })
    }
},
```

It does not works, it disable all date

so if you use axios, it doesn't run the statement in the response

is this a bug in the vuetify datepicker?

Or Look at this : https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/mddPjKZ?editors=1010

Should date 2019-10-17 is enabled

Because it in axios, it does not work

Comment: What is the actual and expected result?

Comment: @Michael it is array. but it call ajax/api without stopping

Answer (score 0):

You can use created hook to add your synchronous function, then trigger the allowedDates function to updated the datepicker

Find the code below:

```
    new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    date: '2019-10-15',
    availableDates: [],
    id: 5,
  }),
  methods: {
    allowedDates(a) {
      return this.availableDates.includes(a);
    },
    pickerUpdate: async function(val, id) {
      // write your async call here
       console.log('from picker update ' + val + '  id: ' + id );
      var tempDates = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        var res = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/barbier')
          .then((response) => {
            // tempDates.push("2019-10-17")
          }); 
        console.log(res);
      }
      tempDates = ["2019-10-17"] // here i have hardcoded the value
      // in your case push the available dates from server response
       this.availableDates = tempDates;
      this.allowedDates();
    },
  },
})

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-date-picker
        v-model="date"
        :allowed-dates="allowedDates"
        class="mt-4"
        @update:picker-date="pickerUpdate($event, id)"
      ></v-date-picker>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Updated codepen:

https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/XWWdxKW?editors=1010

Comment: actual i need parameter date(a) to pass to api. The actual api like this : `https://my-api/schedules/${a}`. a was taken from `allowedDates(a) {`

Comment: alloweddates is a function given by vuetify datepicker. It works like, when you are in a particluar month lets say october 2019, it triggers alloweddates function 31 times startes from 2109-10-01 ..... 2019-10-31 thses dates are the value of a, if you do console log, you will get the same as output printed. Inside allowedDates function if you have some condition to filter only selected dates then your should have to return true, if it is false, it disables those dates in october month. Same as If you switch to November-2019 again it triggers 30 times. What exactly you wanted to do here?

Comment: I know it. But my case is it will call api 31 times based on the date parameter. The first : call `https://my-api/schedules/2019-10-01`. the second : call `https://my-api/schedules/2019-10-02`etc

Comment: this api call is 'post' call or get call which returns boolean ?

Comment: this api is `get`

Comment: There are two clarifications here, allowedDates function is a synchronous operation, You can use Vue watcher to achieve the async task. If the month is changed, you can hit the api for all dates in a month. Is this solution resolves your issue

Comment: I had do it using watch. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58385240/can-i-pass-a-parameter-by-pickerdate-vuetify. But my problem is i can not pass parameter id. I need id to call api. My actual api, there exist id too. Like this : `https://my-api/schedules/id/1/date/2019-10-02`

Comment: You can still access your id via ref updated pen is here https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/XWWdxKW?editors=1010

Comment: Not yes. I'm check it. the result is key.How can I get the value of id? and how do i display it on allowedDates? because in docs, allowedDate uses methods. not watch

Comment: When a month is changes you can get the updated value in watcher, using this.$refs will have the id set in ref, since allowedDates is a synchronous call. That’s why watched can do asynchronous operation on changing to differ to month

Comment: I'm still confused. Can you updated it using codepen?

Comment: See the updated codepemn https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/XWWdxKW?editors=1010

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200917/discussion-between-chans-and-success-man).

Comment: Do upvote if this resolves your issue.., Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm still confused to update allowedDates. Can you show it with codepen? after it is solved, I will accept your answer and be upvote

Comment: Can you help this case?